# "Could not locate google-services.json or GoogleService-info.plist files" iOS Project, Unity, Mac Computer

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, game-development, info.plist

I've been trying for the past two hours to figure this thing out! So I already created a project within my Firebase account; an iOS project. Downloaded the google-service-Info.plist files.

If I click Import New Asset and attempt to search for the file.. can't added it like that, I have to drag it into my folder.

I'm aware that the file must be put within the root folder (which I have done many times now), but I still encounter the same error message.

Could not locate google-services.json or GoogleService-info.plist files"

I removed all the Firebase files (SDK), re-installed them,.. same thing.. 
I also deleted the GoogleService-info.plist file and downloaded a brand new one, same thing!!! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYfQ9.png)

I'm currently using Unity 2018.2.1f1, My computer: macOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6

Comment: Can you make sure that this file is part of the Copy Bundle Resources In Build Phases of the respective target.

Comment: @SachinVas thank you for your suggestion! Could you please explain me how to check that?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @SachinVas Microsoft Visual Studio!

Comment: This is the whole error message: "Could not locate google-services.json or GoogleService-Info.plist files.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:UpdateJson(Boolean, LogMessage, LogMessage) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.sXL81rhJWV/firebase/app/client/unity/editor/src/GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:203)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Comment: Thank you @SachinVas I already went through it, but I willl double check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have same problem.
Add IOS and Android build component for Unity. Switch to the platform Android. It resolve you problem.
Check SDK status. See in screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with iOS components? If you're referring to the components to deploy games on those platforms (I already do). Do you think that by switching platforms it may help? For example changing it to Android and later on back to iOS? That's what you did or am I wrong? Thank you for prompt response!

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN!!!! @MatthewP All I need to do it was changing the platform!! Probably went wrong in the background & wasn't reading properly the GoogleServiceInfo file so by changing platform it did the work!!!

Comment: This worked for me: I actually had to switch from Android, back to Windows, Mac & Linux Standalone. Then switch back to Android again to generate the correct file.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me right after adding a `GoogleService-info.plist` to a project that only had Android support before.

Doing `Assets` -> `Reimport All` also worked for me to get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed the step where you generate those files on Firebase.

Generate them from your Firebase console by clicking the Unity icon in your project overview page. See more complete documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)